# SQL returns duplicates

Tags: sql, duplicates

The sql below returns duplicates.  How do I remove duplicates?

```sql
SELECT filteredUni_Reward.uni_statename, uni_rewardtypename, 
       filteredUni_Reward.uni_agencycode, filteredUni_Reward.uni_agencyidname,  
       filtereduni_reward.uni_contactidname, uni_lineofbusinessname, 
       uni_rewardamount, uni_rewarddate, uni_rewardnumber, uni_statusname, 
       uni_approvedbyidname, filteredUni_Reward.createdbyname, 
       filteredUni_Reward.createdon, filteredUni_Reward.owneridname, 
       uni_npnnumber, uni_contacttinverificationname  
FROM filteredUni_Reward 
LEFT JOIN FilteredContact 
         ON filteredcontact.contactid = uni_contactid
INNER JOIN FilteredUni_AgentLicense 
         ON filtereduni_agentlicense.uni_agentlicenseid = uni_agentlicenseid
WHERE filteredUni_Reward.uni_statusname = 'paid' 
      and filteredUni_Reward.statecodename = 'Active' 
      and filteredUni_Reward.createdon >= '2014-01-01 00:00:00'
```

Comment: Care to actually **show** the sample data and what "duplicates" are returned??

Comment: Agree with marc_s - showing the duplicate data will allow us to determine what's causing the duplicates. 3/4 of the time, duplicates are caused by table joins, but without the query results or sample data, we won't be able to determine which table contains the 'many' side of the table relationship causing the duplicates

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a `distinct` in the `select` statement? Without some data examples, that is the only suggestion you are likely to get for removing duplicates from the results of a select statement.

[Reference for DISTINCT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp)